# Making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game

Tags: python

I am making a Rock, Paper, Scissors game.

The code below works, but there are two critical things missing and I would really like to know how to implement this:

1. In case of a tie, the players must be able to choose again. So the break statement must go but what is needed to go back to the while loop and play again?
2. And the same goes for the end of a game. Players must be able to play again. I think it is the same code as the above.

The answer would be really helpful as it really helps me understand the while loop more.

```py
def rps():

    play = True

    player1 = input('Player1: rock, paper of scissors? ')
    player2 = input('Player2: rock, paper of scissors? ')

    while play:
        if player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'rock': # deze methode werkt niet om opnieuw weer te beginnen
            print ('Tie! Pick again')
            break
        elif player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'paper':
            print('Player 2 won')
            break
        elif player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors':
            print ('Speler 1 won')
            break
        elif player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock':
            print('Speler 1 won')
            break
        elif player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'paper':
            print('Tie! Pick again')
            continue
        elif player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors':
            print('Speler 2 won')
            break
        elif player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock':
            print('Speler 2 won')
            break
        elif player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper':
            print('Speler 1 won')
            break
        elif player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'scissors':
            print('Tie! Pick again')
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the gameplay loop in a second while loop. Do not break on ties. Input for the gameplay loop happens in the gameplay loop. Input for quit or play happens and is assessed before the gameplay loop.

```
while True:
    print("Welcome to Rock, Paper, Scissors.")
    gameplay = input("(P)lay or (Q)uit?")
        if (gameplay == 'Q'):
             break
        else:
             while True:
                player1 = input('Player1: rock, paper of scissors? ')
                player2 = input('Player2: rock, paper of scissors? ')
                {Gameplay Logic}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This helps me a lot!

Comment: np it's what i'm here for

Answer (score 0):

This code should solve serve your purpose

```
def rps():

    play = True

    player1 = input('Player1: rock, paper of scissors? ')
    player2 = input('Player2: rock, paper of scissors? ')

    while play:
        if player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'rock': # deze methode werkt niet om opnieuw weer te beginnen
            print ('Tie! Pick again')
        elif player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'paper':
            print('Player 2 won')
            if input('Type c to continue playing, anything else to quit') == 'y':
                pass
            else:
                break
        elif player1 == 'rock' and player2 == 'scissors':
            print ('Speler 1 won')
            if input('Type c to continue playing, anything else to quit') == 'c':
                pass
            else:
                break
        elif player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'rock':
            print('Speler 1 won')
            if input('Type c to continue playing, anything else to quit') == 'c':
                pass
            else:
                break
        elif player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'paper':
            print('Tie! Pick again')

        elif player1 == 'paper' and player2 == 'scissors':
            print('Speler 2 won')
            if input('Type c to continue playing, anything else to quit') == 'c':
                pass
            else:
                break
        elif player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'rock':
            print('Speler 2 won')
            if input('Type c to continue playing, anything else to quit') == 'c':
                pass
            else:
                break
        elif player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'paper':
            print('Speler 1 won')
            if input('Type c to continue playing, anything else to quit') == 'c':
                pass
            else:
                break
        elif player1 == 'scissors' and player2 == 'scissors':
            print('Tie! Pick again')

        player1 = input('Player1: rock, paper of scissors? ')
        player2 = input('Player2: rock, paper of scissors? ')
```

> The code can be optimised and simplified by doing away few if and
>   else, but I kept this for your understanding and making minor tweak in
>   your code.

Comment: Thank you too! This is also a good way for me to understand logic more and more:)

Comment: Glad I could help you. You can click on the tick icon to accept the answer if it helped you.